# How can I change values of global variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, console, global-variables

I am trying to change values of global variables, but the changes which I made don't take affect on global variable.
Here is my code

```js
console.log(clientInformation.doNotTrack)
```

Its output is null

```js
clientInformation.doNotTrack = "1"
console.log(clientInformation.doNotTrack)
```

Output is still null, but required output should be "1"

Comment: Change the Question.. you are asking about Browser Settings. `ClientInformation` or `Navigator`. As far as I know, you can only read the value if it is enabled or not. you cannot change it via javascript.

Comment: i want to update some field in ClientInformation object, you can consider it for some other object which has already some fields from this i want to update only one field in that object, and the rest object will remain same. Thanks

Comment: u cannot update the `ClientInformation` object. Go to the browser settings and change the Do Not Track setting https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2790761?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en . The value will be 1